# Linq Query to get List of Objects and for Each of Object get another nested List

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

In my MVC application I want to get all the `Tests` which are parent of `Headings`, Headings are parent of `Parameters` and Parameters are Parent of `Drop Downs`, like:

`Tests` --> `List of Headings`-->`List of Parameters` -->`List of Drop Downs`

In my Controller I am trying to get lists with in list:

```
var getAllReport = (
           from tests in _db.tblPatientSelectedTests.ToList()
           from heading in _db.tblHeadings.Where(x=>x.TestID == tests.TestId).ToList()
           from par in _db.tblParameters.Where(x=>x.HeadingID == heading.HeadingID).ToList()
           from drp in _db.DropDownValues.Where(x =>x.ParemeterID == par.ParameterId).ToList()
           select new
           {
               Tests = tests,
               Headings = heading,
               Parameters = par,
               DropDowns = drp
           }
           ).ToList();
ViewBag.GetAllReports = getAllReport;
```

I want it to be strongly typed, so I have tried to make a class like this:

```
public class allparams
    {
        public List<tblPatientSelectedTest> Tests { get; set; }
        public List<tblHeading> Headings { get; set; }
        public List<tblParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
        public List<DropDownValue> DropDowns { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to use that class `allparams` in my linq so I can have strongly typed view.

I want to populate results in my view like this:

```
@foreach(Tests item in ViewBag.GetAllReports)
{
 do some stuff 
@foreach(Headings item in ViewBag.GetAllReports)
 {
  do some stuff and so on for other nested lists 
 }
}
```

Comment: Consider having class Test including a List<Heading>Headings property, and Heading having a List<Parameter> Parameters property and Parameter having a List<DropDownValue> DropDowns, i.e., a hierarchy that reflects what I understand is your object model.  To figure out how to glue it all together, play with Linq2Sql and Entity Framework to see what they do (or, use them directly).

Comment: Maybe do this as stored procedure in the db and return a Hierarchal  DTO object of what is needed.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `@foreach(Headings item in ViewBag.GetAllReports)` to do? Iterate through all headings of all reports? That doesn't seem very useful. Wouldn't you rather have a separate list of headings for each report?

Comment: Flydog57 thank you it is a good option by the way

Comment: what is happening with your current linq?

Comment: I am getting values but not in expected hierarchy

Comment: And also this is a general list I want it to be `List` of `allparams`

Comment: "I am getting values but not in expected hierarchy " can you elaborate

Comment: to get List for `allparams` all you need to do is add constructor in `allparams` and change `select new
           {` to  `select new allparams
           {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using EF.

Your problem can be solved through Linq's `Include()` method.

```
var getAllReport = _db.tblPatientSelectedTests
.Include("tblHeadings")
.Include("tblParameters")
.Include("DropDownValue")
.ToList();
```

The `Include()` allows you to fetch the related entities from the database as part of the same query. The details can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx).

And later you can just use it as follows:

```
@foreach(Tests test in ViewBag.GetAllReports)
{
    //do some stuff 
    @foreach(Headings heading in test.tblHeadings)
    {
        //do some stuff and so on for other nested lists 
        //and so on... for tblParameters and DropDownValue
    }
}
```

Just a suggestion though, the data access logic should be kept in a separate layer for maintainability reasons.